# Saving menus causes 404 category not found

Tags: joomla-3.3.x

I've looked around quite a bit for a solution to this problem, but haven't found anything that works yet, nor anyone talking about it for Joomla 3. Most posts about this online are years old and for Joomla 2.5, and none of them actually offer a solution.

The problem is that every time I save a menu item, it then produces a "404 - Category not found" screen, and the url changes from myurl.com/alias-here to myurl.com/Category/alias-here. This started happening after an upgrade from 2.5 to 3.3 (and the site is currently upgraded to the most recent version). The site was also upgraded from 1.5 about 2 years ago and worked fine for that time.

The temporary fix that a lot of people are doing, is doing a menu "rebuild" at the top of the menu manager. That does work, but it's not a good solution for website with lots of changes and additions being made daily, because every time you save one, you have to remember to click the build button. It seems like this might be a bug to submit??

Anyone experience this and know a fix??? I don't get stumped often, but I'm really not sure about this one.

Comment: i have the extactly same Problem - if i open & save a menu-item it adds Links/Categories/ infront of the path, which leads to 404 Error and after hit the rebuild-button, the pathes are fixed again. Did you find a solution for that problem?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this just a few days ago. If you remake the menu item at the top level, then shift all the childs into it, this problem goes away, for all time. It's something where the alias and the menu item id are tied together and confuddled. New menu item id, problem goes away. I know that's a lot of work - but if you do it once, then it's fixed.

Comment: Since you mentioned lots of work, I should mention that the menu manager supports batch operations for moving a selection of menu items at once, just in case somebody needs to do this without knowing that.